# Fixed jQuery/JSON - Twitch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitch

So I need some help. Can someone get this working for me? It should fetch data from the JSON and turn the streams into iFrames. Can someone help me out? - UPDATE: It does that now. But it fetches some Undefinied channel. How do I fix that?

```
<script>
     var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
     $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
     var streamGame = json.streams[0].game;
     var streamThumb = json.streams[0].preview;
     var streamVideo = json.streams[0].name;
     $('#twitch').append('<li><iframe src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe></li>');
    }
   );
</script>
```

You can check the JSON at https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams

Also, the streams should be parsed like this:

Comment: I guess the JSON you provided is the dummy one. If it is the actual JSON then in the 1st script you need to do json.streams instead of json.follows.

Comment: @Bkjain655 I've updated the post. I'm currently stuck at that code. I've changed it to json.streams . Any idea why it won't display iFrames inside the #twitch div?
The console returns that i is not defined. I have no idea what it does honestly..

Comment: @Bkjain655 Okay, updated the post again. It is semi working now.

Comment: @JohnDetHR : 1 thing which I observed is there no such name property in the JSON. It is present inside channel object. So i guess it should json.streams[0].channel.name; Also I tried in fiddle and it is loading fine but there are some CORS issues.https://jsfiddle.net/mhyt72xr/

Comment: @Bkjain655 Okay that works quite good. I have two more questions. I'd be so thankful if you could help me out. The first one is; how do I use that script to display an unlimited amount of streams ( not just the first one from the JSON list ). And the second one:  How do I make a script similar to that one except it fetches data from: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top And displays the names of the Top 10 games.

Comment: 2 Basic concepts - For Loop and Functions are the answer for both the questions.